# Generate List Based on Multiple Criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with election results. The spreadsheet shows the number of votes each candidate received for each post in each constituency. A row in the sheet lists the constituency, the candidate's party, the candidate's name, and the number of votes he/she received.

I want to have a summary sheet which show a list of the winning candidates, i.e. the candidates with the most votes received in each constituency. How would I generate this list from the sheet listing all election results?

[image]

Here is an example of a basic pivot table. But I want a list that only shows the top vote recipient per constituency.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with Pivot tables at all? I think that is going to be the quickest/easiest option for you here.

Comment: Yes - I am familiar with PivotTables. So, I can make PivotTable that shows all candidates by constituency. However, how do I only list the one candidate with the most votes per constituency? See second screenshot above.

Comment: Okay, so now right-click on any of the non-bolded numbers, and select summarize by --> Max.

Comment: Then, right-click any of the people's names and select Filter --> Top 10 (adjust it to top 1 items instead of top 10, by Max of Total Votes Cast for Candidate).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new sheet with a list of all the possible constituencies, you could use an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter). In A2:A10 I have the names of the candidates, B2:B10 is the votes they received, C2:C10 is the constituency. Columns E and F would be on your 2nd sheet that lists only the winners. [picture of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuM8j.jpg)

Here is the formula from F2, just copy it down as many constituencies as you have:

{=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(MAX(IF($C$2:$C$10=E2,$B$2:$B$10)),IF($C$2:$C$10=E2,0)))}

Let me know if that helps. - Joe

Comment: That's helpful. I think I almost got it to work. See this Google Sheet: http://bit.ly/1X3muQC    / it appears to be returning the candidate with the least votes. "Okenn Kandida" here means "no candidate", i.e. blank votes.

Comment: I am not sure how it worked for me before but I think I was able to fix it in your Google spreadsheet by adding the $C$2:$C$601 to the last IF statement.=arrayformula(INDEX($A$2:$A$601,MATCH(MAX(IF($D$2:$D$601=F2,$C$2:$C$601)),IF($D$2:$D$601=F2,$C$2:$C$601),0)))